# Kotlin optional, or something similar

Tags: sql, kotlin, null

i find kotlin intresting, but also i find it very difficult to find any understandable enough documentation about how to *properly* deal with nulls.

Im a Java dev, so i should be able to pivot to kotlin pretty easily, yet i find myself struggeling with with simple stuff.

following SQL query:

```
 @Query(value = "FROM Address a WHERE a.userId = :userId")
 fun findAddressByuserId(@Param("userId") userId: String) : List<Address>?
```

Can i somehow get rid of the ? at the end of `List<Address>?` ?
it is possible for SQL to not return anything, so produce null.

and after the query i try to map result but now that takes `!!` because of nullable list.

```
customerAddresses!!.map { a -> a.email = email.email }
```

Thank you!

Comment: The official kotlin documentation should provide you with the wanted information. Nullability is expained [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

In your `map`-sample you are using a lambda that maps `Address` to `Unit` and has a side effect, resulting in a `List<Unit>` what clearly is not what you intend.
The [Kotlin Koans](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Collections/Introduction/Task.kt) explain working with collections very well

Comment: Thank you @FrankNeblung but im still quite confused. map Address to Unit? Kotlin documentation says "This type corresponds to the void type in Java." and List<Void> is propably not what i should be thinking here. Can you write an short example about how i should map input string to every objects email filed, in this list? input is type of Email which has email field inside. much thanks to you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by _how i should map input string to every objects email filed_. Given that you have `val addresses: List<Address>` and `val newEmail: String`, you might want to do one of the following: 1. assign each address a new email: `addresses.forEach { it.email = newEmail }` 2. collect the addresses' emails `val emails: List<String> = addresses.map { it.email }`, 3. associate the addresses by its email `val map: Map<String, Address> = addresses.associateBy { it.email }`. But you should definitely ask a dedicated question for that concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If SQL does not return anything, that would correspond to 0 found item, **i.e. an empty list**, rather than no list at all. I would also model it accordingly:

```
@Query(value = "FROM Address a WHERE a.userId = :userId")
fun findAddressByUserId(@Param("userId") userId: String) : List<Address>
```

That will also let you omit the `!!` when using it.

I don't know the library you're using -- but if it strictly does not allow to have return types non-nullable, then you could write a wrapper function that just calls the other one. Use the `?:` (Elvis) operator for that case:

```
@Query(value = "FROM Address a WHERE a.userId = :userId")
private fun _findAddressByUserId(@Param("userId") userId: String) : List<Address>?

fun findAddressByUserId(userId: String) : List<Address> =
    _findAddressByUserId(userId) ?: emptyList()
```